# Parse the array without a key before the square brackets in SwiftyJson?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swifty-json

Am fetching the country list from server. And the server response is like this.

```
[
    {
        "CountryID": 2,
        "Name": "Afghanistan",
        "Code": "AFG",
        "CreatedDate": "2018-01-09T02:05:02.08"
    },
    {
        "CountryID": 3,
        "Name": "Aland Islands",
        "Code": "ALA",
        "CreatedDate": "2018-01-09T02:05:02.08"
    }
]
```

Am using SwiftyJSON to convert the response as Json like this.

```
if let value = response.result.value {
   let json = JSON(value)                        
   let countryListData = CountryList(fromJson: json)
   completionHandler(true, countryListData)
}
```

And the Country List class be like this.

```
class CountryList {
    var countries: [Country]!
    init(fromJson json: JSON!) {
        let countryArray = json[0].arrayValue
        for countryJson in countryArray {
            let value = Country(fromJson: countryJson)
            countries.append(value)
        }
    }
}

class Country {
    var code : String!
    var countryID : Int!
    var createdDate : String!
    var name : String!
    init(fromJson json: JSON!){
        if json == nil{
            return
        }
        code = json["Code"].stringValue
        countryID = json["CountryID"].intValue
        createdDate = json["CreatedDate"].stringValue
        name = json["Name"].stringValue
    }
}
```

How can I parse this array without a key before the square brackets in SwiftyJson? It doesn't give the array objects correctly.

I know this to do it in normal way like will convert the response as dictionary. But client advised to use SwiftyJson. So only am trying this in SwiftyJson.

Give me some suggestion and don't mark this question as duplicate. Because I don't get any reference from the internet to convert this by using SwiftyJson.

Comment: What do you meant by parse array without a key before the square brackets?

Comment: Try to replace json[0].arrayValue with json.arrayValue

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya - Thanks for your quick response. I tried it like this way also but now also am getting an empty array.

Comment: Why write this `let countryArray = json[0].arrayValue`, your data is array so no need to  `json[0].arrayValue`, only use  `json.arrayValue`

Comment: Or try  directly  `for (index,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
    // Do something you want
}`

Comment: @AshvinGudaliya - Thanks for your response. I tried it too but array is empty. When I print the json alone it prints the array. But when I print json.arrayValue it prints empty.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues in your class `CountryList`

```
class CountryList {
  // 1. the countries var is not initialized
  // var countries: [Country]!
  // Initialize it like below
  var countries = [Country]()
  init(fromJson json: JSON!) {
    // 2 issue is that json itself is an array so no need of doing json[0].arrayValue
    let countryArray = json.arrayValue
    for countryJson in countryArray {
      let value = Country(fromJson: countryJson)
      countries.append(value)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. json.arrayValue itself is emplty. But when I print json it will print like this. [{"CountryID":2,"Name":"Afghanistan","Code":"AFG","CreatedDate":"2018-01-09T02:05:02.08"},{"CountryID":3,"Name":"Aland Islands","Code":"ALA","CreatedDate":"2018-01-09T02:05:02.08"},...]

Comment: Please post your whole json here : http://jsoneditoronline.org and send me the link after saving it online. The above changes worked for me for the json that you provided in the quesiton

Comment: Thanks for your effort Inder. This is the link https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=0fa1720a4dd9d2e45838771cbf08facb

Comment: Your json seems perfect and when I replace that with my demo project it's working fine in my demo project : https://www.dropbox.com/s/o64vyyi03yg9lyc/SwiftyJsonTest.zip?dl=1

Comment: Thanks Inder. I will check it now and let you know.

Comment: It is working when the json created by us. But it doesn't work when the json converted from server response. So I changed class CountryList {
    var countries = [Country]()
    init(fromArray array: NSArray!) {
        for countryJson in array {
            let json = JSON(countryJson)
            let value = Country(fromJson: json)
            countries.append(value)
        }
    }
} and calling like this 
                            let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!) as? NSArray
     let countryListData = CountryList(fromArray: array!)

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answer by myself. I converted the response as NSArray like this

```
do {
   let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!) as? NSArray
   let countryListData = CountryList(fromArray: array!)
   completionHandler(true, countryListData)
} catch {
   print("Exception occured \(error))")
}
```

And changed the CountryList class like this

```
class CountryList {
    var countries = [Country]()
    init(fromArray array: NSArray!) {
        for countryJson in array {
            let value = Country(fromJson: countryJson)
            countries.append(value)
        }
    }
}

class Country {
    var code : String!
    var countryID : Int!
    var createdDate : String!
    var name : String!
    init(fromJson json: JSON!){
        if json == nil{
            return
        }
        code = json["Code"].stringValue
        countryID = json["CountryID"].intValue
        createdDate = json["CreatedDate"].stringValue
        name = json["Name"].stringValue
    }
}
```

Now its working what I expected. Thanks for all your comments and answer.